# Factoring a polynomial with complex coefficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

> Given  $$3z^2+6z+3i=0$$ Find the complex roots and write in the form $a+bi$.

I want to see how to factor it when there is an $i$ being multiplied by the constant.

Comment: Divide through by 3 first. Then try completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

$$3z^2+6z+3i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$3(z^2+2z+i)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z^2+2z+i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot i}}{2\cdot 1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4-4\cdot i}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4-4i}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{-2+\sqrt{4-4i}}{2}  \vee z=\frac{-2-\sqrt{4-4i}}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-4i}  \vee z=-1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4-4i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+\sqrt{1-i}  \vee z=-1-\sqrt{1-i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2^{\frac{3}{4}}}-\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2^{\frac{3}{4}}}i  \vee z=-1-\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2^{\frac{3}{4}}}+\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2^{\frac{3}{4}}}i $$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by $3$

$$z^{2}+2z+i=0$$

Completing the square

$$(z+1)^{2}=1-i$$

$$z=-1+\sqrt{1-i}$$

where $1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4}=\sqrt{2}e^{i7\pi/4}$

$$\sqrt{1-i}=\sqrt[4]{2}e^{-i\pi/8}$$

$$\sqrt{1-i}=\sqrt[4]{2}e^{7i\pi/8}$$

So the solutions are

$$z=-1+\sqrt[4]{2}e^{-i\pi/8}$$

$$z=-1+\sqrt[4]{2}e^{7i\pi/8}$$

Comment: You've got one of the two solutions.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have both, there are two answers to $\sqrt{1-i}$. It is on the last line.

Comment: Your last line is wrong because $e^{-i\pi/8}$ is not equal to $e^{7i\pi/8}$. What you need to say is that the square root is EITHER $\sqrt[4] 2 e^{-i\pi/8}$ OR $\sqrt[4]2 e^{7i\pi/8}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy it is peculiar to express the values of a multivalued function.

Comment: Completing the square, I guess that $z=-1\pm \sqrt{1-i}$

Comment: I suppose that would have been an easier way to express it @Claude Leibovici I just thought it would be good to see how to get those roots.